# How can I force Outlook 2019 to notify changes in the email store to the gatherer of Wsearch?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

Configuration:

Edition  Windows 11 Pro, Version 21H2
OS build              22000.348
Experience         Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.348.0
Microsoft® Outlook® 2019 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20270) 64-bit, Home and business 2019

Weird Windows Search issue, example steps as follwing:

1. Boot PC
2. Create test folder c:\mytest and create testfile.txt with following content: bbbccc
3. Add this folder to the included locations for indexing in advanced search options of Windows OS, check if MS Search finds string bbbccc (in my case it does immediately after having created testfile.txt) => so MS Search works because it found the file with "bbbccc" string immediately.
4. Open Outlook 2019
5. Download new emails
6. Search in Outlook search bar for one of the new downloaded emails
7. My search doesn’t result anything !
8. Extra test: I use another email address and send from that email a test email with subject "test email" and message in body following string "xxxyyyzzz"
9. I wait for the email to come in / download in Outlook this new email, then I search for xxxyyyzzz and… no result !
10. I check the index with a Powershell script to double check if the new downloaded email isn’t in the WSearch index subsystem (Powershell script pasted at bottom of this question)
11. Indeed, the xxxyyyzzz teststring doesn’t show in the systemindex… (Powershell script zero results)
12. When I reboot: new email shows in Powershell script and of course also Outlook finds the xxxyyyzzz test string email in the Outlook Search Bar
13. I am not a WSearch specialist but from my understanding there is no crawling involved with Outlook, Outlook should notify the gatherer of the WSearch.
14. If assumption 13 is correct… then what is happening here?
    a.  Is Outlook not notifying the gatherer of WSearch?
    b.  Or is Outlook notifying correctly but Wsearch is failing ?
    C.  Is there a way to check if WSearch is receiving the mapi notifications from Outlook (= can we “listen” or monitor what the gatherer of WSearch receives?)

I tried the usual first aid solutions: repair online Office, rebuild the index... same end result.

Please note: this issue is the same on different PC’s in my office, all which upgraded to Win11 Pro 64bit. I never had this issue on Win10 Pro 64bit…

Powershell script to search for xxxyyyzzz string in WSearch Index database:

```
function Invoke-WindowsSearch
{
    param
    (
     [Parameter()][string] $SearchString = ""
    )
    $SearchString = $SearchString.Replace("'","''")
    $query   = "select System.Message.datereceived, System.ItemNameDisplay from systemindex where contains('$SearchString')"
    $provider = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO.1;Extended?PROPERTIES='Application=Windows'"
    $adapter  = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDBDataAdapter -Argument $query, $provider
    $results = new-object System.Data.DataSet

    $adapter.Fill($results)
    $results.Tables[0]
}

Invoke-WindowsSearch xxxyyyzzz
```